# Cytools failing to build metadata

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pip, cython

Im using python 3.11 and coding in vs code
while trying to install some requirements im getting the following error
` Collecting cytoolz==0.11.2 (from -r requirements.txt (line 11))
Using cached cytoolz-0.11.2.tar.gz (481 kB)
Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

```
  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [73 lines of output]

      Error compiling Cython file:
      ------------------------------------------------------------
      ...
          cdef readonly object func
          cdef readonly tuple args
          cdef readonly dict keywords
          cdef public object __doc__
          cdef public object __name__
          cdef public object __module__
                             ^
      ------------------------------------------------------------

      cytoolz\functoolz.pxd:18:23: '__module__' redeclared

      Error compiling Cython file:
      ------------------------------------------------------------
      ...
          cdef readonly object func
          cdef readonly tuple args
          cdef readonly dict keywords
          cdef public object __doc__
          cdef public object __name__
          cdef public object __module__
               ^
      ------------------------------------------------------------

      cytoolz\functoolz.pxd:18:9: Compiler crash in AnalyseDeclarationsTransform

      File 'ModuleNode.py', line 203, in analyse_declarations: ModuleNode(functoolz.pxd:1:0,
          full_module_name = 'cytoolz.functoolz',
          is_pxd = True)
      File 'Nodes.py', line 393, in analyse_declarations: StatListNode(functoolz.pxd:1:0)
      File 'Nodes.py', line 5449, in analyse_declarations: CClassDefNode(functoolz.pxd:10:5,
          as_name = 'curry',
          class_name = 'curry',
          in_pxd = True,
          module_name = '',
          punycode_class_name = 'curry',
          visibility = 'private')
      File 'Nodes.py', line 393, in analyse_declarations: StatListNode(functoolz.pxd:11:4)
      File 'Nodes.py', line 1529, in analyse_declarations: CVarDefNode(functoolz.pxd:18:9,
          in_pxd = True,
          modifiers = [...]/0,
          visibility = 'public')

      Compiler crash traceback from this point on:
        File "C:\Users\zaidr\Documents\DYDX\venv\Lib\site-packages\Cython\Compiler\Nodes.py", line 1529, in analyse_declarations
          self.entry = dest_scope.declare_var(
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\zaidr\Documents\DYDX\venv\Lib\site-packages\Cython\Compiler\Symtab.py", line 2388, in declare_var
          entry = self.declare(name, cname, type, pos, visibility)
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\zaidr\Documents\DYDX\venv\Lib\site-packages\Cython\Compiler\Symtab.py", line 550, in declare
          entries[name].already_declared_here()
        File "C:\Users\zaidr\Documents\DYDX\venv\Lib\site-packages\Cython\Compiler\Symtab.py", line 262, in already_declared_here
          error(self.pos, "Previous declaration is here")
        File "C:\Users\zaidr\Documents\DYDX\venv\Lib\site-packages\Cython\Compiler\Errors.py", line 178, in error
          raise InternalError(message)
      InternalError: Internal compiler error: Previous declaration is here
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
        File "C:\Users\zaidr\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-so8rcdso\cytoolz_bdaa1aa481cb42ed84ccd4148f91edf3\setup.py", line 87, in <module>
          ext_modules = cythonize(ext_modules, force=not is_dev)
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\zaidr\Documents\DYDX\venv\Lib\site-packages\Cython\Build\Dependencies.py", line 1134, in cythonize
          cythonize_one(*args)
        File "C:\Users\zaidr\Documents\DYDX\venv\Lib\site-packages\Cython\Build\Dependencies.py", line 1301, in cythonize_one
          raise CompileError(None, pyx_file)
      Cython.Compiler.Errors.CompileError: cytoolz/functoolz.pyx
      [1/5] Cythonizing cytoolz/dicttoolz.pyx
      [2/5] Cythonizing cytoolz/functoolz.pyx
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```

`

I have vs build tools installed already and iv upgraded pip already as well

Comment: What command did you use to install it? Is there an error when using `pip install cytoolz` directly? Try using `pip install setuptools==58.2.0` to install the fixed version `setuptools`.